# How to fix RuntimeError CUDA error CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE when calling `cublasSgemm`?

Tags: pytorch

When training some models on a working cuda environment, you can get the error `RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE when calling cublasSgemm( handle, opa, opb, m, n, k, &alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, &beta, c, ldc)`

What does it means and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you provide the full error trace?

Answer (score 4):

It may be an incomplete error reporting of a shape error:

A mismatch in dimension of a nn.Linear module and its inpput, for example `x.shape == [a, b]` going into a `nn.Linear(c, c, bias=False)` with c not matching the shape of x, will result in this error message.

See the [Pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-cuda-error-cublas-status-invalid-value-when-calling-cublassgemm-handle-opa-opb-m-n-k-alpha-a-lda-b-ldb-beta-c-ldc/124544/4) conversation.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when using fairseq. Cuda version installed on my amazon linux 2 is 11.5 and torch version is 1.13.1. I uninstalled it through and installed version 1.12.1 which took me past this error stage.

I later also tried installing torch along with cuda this way and it also worked fine:
pip install torch==1.13.1+cu116 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116

Comment: Same issue with https://github.com/openai/CLIP.